# Include section number when referencing enum item

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have something like this:

```
\section{a section name}
\subsection{a subsection name}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{itm:first} Item one
  \item Item two
  \item Item three
\end{enumerate}
I am saying something else about \ref{itm:first}
```

The bottom line of the output looks like this: `I am saying something else about 1`. 
Is there a way to include the section number the list item is in, in the reference to it? This would look like `I am saying something else about 1.1.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right you want normal numbering of the enumeration items but numbering with subsection numbering in the reference. There are two commands you can play with here, `\theenumi` and `\labelenumi`. They are normally (like in article) defined like:

```
\newcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}} %% Format for references
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}.  %% Printed by \item (add '.')
```

To get the special format for the references you can do

```
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}%% references with subsection numbering
```

But even if it is possible, I doubt it is recommended. The references is there for the reader to find a specific place in the text, and using different formats in the `\item` and the reference will be confusing.

An alternative way is to add the extra numbering to both the `\item` and the reference with

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}
```

Then, with the normal definition of `\labelenumi` the same is used with an additional period.

A third alternative, that I would prefer, is to just in the text a specification of which enumeration list you mean, e.g. `in Subsection~\ref{sec:Mysubsection}`.

All the above versions are given in one file below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}%% references with subsection numbering
\section{a section name}
\subsection{a subsection name}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{itm:first} Item one
  \item Item two
  \item Item three
\end{enumerate}
I am saying something else about item \ref{itm:first}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}%% Back to normal
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}%% Back to normal
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}}%% Add subsection number to item
\section{a section name}
\subsection{a subsection name}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item one
  \item \label{itm:second}Item two
  \item Item three
\end{enumerate}
I am saying something else about item \ref{itm:second}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}%% Back to normal
\section{a section name}
\label{sec:Mysection}
\subsection{a subsection name}
\label{sec:Mysubsection}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item one
  \item Item two
  \item \label{itm:third}Item three
\end{enumerate}
I am saying something else about item \ref{itm:third} in Subsection~\ref{sec:Mysubsection}.
\end{document}
```

[image]