# Reference to items with section number, if in another section

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Consider the document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{a} a
\end{enumerate}

\section{B}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{b} b
\end{enumerate}
Items \ref{b} and \ref{a}.
\end{document}
```

It prints out "Items a and a".

Instead, I'd like it to print out "Items a and 1.a"; i.e., I want the section number included in the reference, but, unlike [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432885/include-section-number-when-referencing-enum-item), *only* if the reference is in another section.

How easily is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put before the reference a (robust) macro that checks the current value of `section` against the value stored when the `\label` was issued.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\labelformat{enumi}{\maybe{section}{\thesection}#1}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\newrobustcmd{\maybe}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#2}=\z@
  \else
    #2.%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{a} a
\end{enumerate}

\section{B}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{b} b
\end{enumerate}
Items \ref{b} and \ref{a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different version from a suggestion by frougon:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\labelformat{enumi}{\maybe{section}{\arabic{section}}{\thesection}#1}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\newrobustcmd{\maybe}[3]{%
  \ifnum#2=\value{#1}%
  \else
    #3.%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{a} a
\end{enumerate}

\section{B}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{b} b
\end{enumerate}
Items \ref{b} and \ref{a}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is smart! Maybe the following: `\labelformat{enumi}{\maybe{section}{\number\value{section}}#1}` and, for the test,  `\ifnum\number\value{#1}=#2 ` would be desirable in case the document author does things like `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textbf{\arabic{section}}}`?

Comment: @frougon If the user adds formatting to `\thesection`, they do at their own risk. One is free to shoot one's own foot, but can't blame the weapon. Anyway, that's a good idea.

Comment: Ah... thanks for your reply! I thought `\thefoobar` was for formatting counter `foobar`. So, if I understand what you mean, `\thefoobar` would be reserved to expandable formatting like `\roman`, `\alph` and similar? And `\p@〈type〉` and `\@seccntformat` would be for “non-expandable formatting”?

Comment: @frougon The idea was good, but now `\maybe` needs three arguments, because I have to store also `\thesection` (which might be nonnumeric).

Comment: You're right, this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I really like that logic. But could you elaborate on @frougon's question, please? I think I suffer from the same misunderstanding about `\thefoobar`.