# Prepend section number to numbered easylist

Tags: sectioning, easylist

Is there a way to prepend the section number to a numbered easylist list?

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432885/include-section-number-when-referencing-enum-item) link but it seems to add it to an enumerated list.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the manual suggests `Style*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\ListProperties(Style*=\thesection.)

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{easylist}
@ First proposition.
@@ Interesting comment.
@@@ A note on the comment.
@@@ Another note.
@@@@ By the way...
@@@@@ This is a subsub...-proposition.
@ Let’s start something new...
\end{easylist}

\section{Second}

\begin{easylist}
@ First proposition.
@@ Interesting comment.
@@@ A note on the comment.
@@@ Another note.
@@@@ By the way...
@@@@@ This is a subsub...-proposition.
@ Let’s start something new...
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]